# How to transform number to float

Tags: javascript

So for rounding I use

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
```

But I also need the decimals like this

```
1 => 1.00
1.5 => 1.50
1.456 => 1.46
```

I achieve this with

```
 num.toFixed(2);
```

but this returns a string, I know this has to be a string. However is there a way to get the same functionality but returning float values, not string?

```
1 is the same amount as 1.00
```

So why do I need those zeros? Because an API I am working with expects float only. Event 1 has to be passed as 1.00 float. Any ideas?

Comment: This problem is logically flawed... You want 1.1 (which is a number) to be represented as "1.10" (which is a string). But in the world of numbers there's no 1.10 because that is 1.1 because there's no significance to the last decimal since it's zero.

Comment: in js 1===1.00, so there's nothing you can do to distinguish those 'two' figures.  Only when converting from/to a string such question may arise.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp exactly, so this is an issue with the api

Comment: Sure that API is written in JavaScript? Both `1` and `1.5` are same type, which is "Number". [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgeLJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When returning the arguments just convert them to floats from string using parseFloat() on the string you get. Formatting is not part of the float type and thus only the value is stored. If you need formatting as well as the value, a custom class should be created.